# Oauth2 Flow , difference between Authorise and Authorisation Grant

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am using this library: https://github.com/manjeshpv/node-oauth2-server-implementation

From my understanding of Oauth2:

```
1)Generate a clientid and clientSecret

2)User use clientId and clientSecret to get a bearerToken

3)Authorisation server returns accessToken to users if valid clientId and clientSecret combination

4)User then use the accessToken to run http post/get api calls (within their scope)
```

In the POSTMAN examples given in the GITHUB, we have

[image]

I noticed Password Grant, Refresh Token ,Client Credential Grant and Authorisation Grant points to the same POST request with the difference in the body.

and the Authorise sample web service, which I assume is that user would have to click in order for the authorisation server to return an access code for user to call scope specific API urls, but somehow access code is needed too, which I'm confused.

[image]

and If I use Client Credential Grant (which I assume is to return an AccessToken using my clientId and clientSecret), then what's the point of the authorise webservice?

[image]

What would be the right flow for this library and webservices example?

Would really appreciate help in this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and the Authorise sample web service, which I assume is that user
>   would have to click in order for the authorisation server to return an
>   access code for user to call scope specific API urls, but somehow
>   access code is needed too, which I'm confused.

Your terminology is a bit confused. Here is a probably most popular OAuth flow:

1. Developer (you) registers OAuth client, receives `clientid` and `clientSecret`
2. User opens some url like oauth.com/authorize, is shown a dialog asking to give some rights to developer's application. (Here clientId is used, but clientSecret is not required)
3. If user agrees, authorization *code* is sent to developer's application (to `redirect_uri` defined at step 1). This code is short-term and cannot be used to access user's data.
4. Developer's application makes POST request to OAuth server with authorization code, `clientId` and `clientSecret` and gets authorization *token* in exchange. This token can be used to access user's data.

> and If I use Client Credential Grant (which I assume is to return an
>   AccessToken using my clientId and clientSecret), then what's the point of the authorise webservice?

Token got by ClientCredentials grant identifies client, but not user. So I guess it is useless in your case.

Comment: Hi @eugene, thanks for the answer. In your point 2 and 3, sent to developer application via the redirect_uri but why bearer {{accesstoken}} is needed too?

Comment: @Gene Authorization code is got without client secret - that's why we first need to exchange code for token (this operation requires client_secret). If you don't need client secret verification - you can use *implicit flow* (it's quite similar to what I've described, but step 3 returns access-token, and authorization code is not used at all)

Comment: i figured it out. What u said makes sense. Client Credentials identifies based on client_id+client secret combination. Thanks!